# Trying to override a dynamically generated inline style

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm trying to quickly fix something that is broken on a wordpress site.  The problem is that someone else created the soup sandwhich and I'm stuck fixing it.  I have an element that shows up in two different sections on the page. The first is a post-status form, the second time it shows up is in a comment-add section that repeats indefinitely on the page.  The block of code works on the comments, but doesn't work on the status form, so I wan't to simply hide it until I figure out how to A) find where the heck the code is being generated, B) fix the issue.

The element has a style that is being dynamically applied (assuming javascript) at load of the element.  It starts off hidden, then something somewhere down the pipe shows it.

Here is what my code looks like, first the element that works:

```
<div class="activity-comments">
  <div class="audio_controls fresh" style>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

The block that is broken:

```
<div id="whats-new-post-in-box">
  <div class="audio_controls fresh" style="display: block;">
    ...
  </div>
<div>
```

So in that first block the code sits without a style in it, which for some odd reason whoever wrote it left the style tag in anyway without any style to apply (completely stupid and malformed code).  But in the second element, the one that's broke, it has a display:block dynamically written in at run time.  I'm trying to figure out how to force it to display:none.  I've tried js, but I'm somehow not calling it correctly (not sure how to call nested elements, I only want the audio_controls within that nested ID but not the other class).

Anyone have any ideas for me?

Comment: `document.getElementById('whats-new-post-in-box').children.removeAttribute('style')`, if you didn't want to go a CSS direction using `!important`.

Comment: If your trying to only hide all preceeding comments, I would do this. #whats-new-post-in-box .audio_controls {display: none !important}  then follow with this, #whats-new-post-in-box .audio_controls:first-child {display: block !important}. That way only the first comment will show. This may help. Also, check to see if in the comment box that it closes correctly the comments and has set_only to 1.  I would post this issue on the wordpressoverflow, they may be able to help  you solve this.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: I expect you'll find that `NodeList`s / `HTMLCollection`s don't have a `removeAttribute` method.

Comment: ah crap sorry forgot the identifier: `document.getElementById('whats-new-post-in-box').children[0].removeAttribute('styl‌​e')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
#whats-new-post-in-box > .audio_controls.fresh {
    display: none !important;
}
```

An `!important` style rule can override an inline style rule (unless the inline style rule is *also* `!important`).

Alternately, with JavaScript on [any modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector):

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#whats-new-post-in-box .audio_controls.fresh");
var n;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
    list[n].style.display = "none";
}
```

For older browsers it's more of a pain:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("whats-new-post-in-box").firstChild;
while (elm) {
    if (elm.className &&
        elm.className.match(/\baudio_controls\b/) &&
        elm.className.match(/\bfresh\b/)) {

        elm.style.display = "none";
    }
    elm = elm.nextSibling;
}
```

Obviously, for the two JS solutions, you need to run that code *after* whatever it is that's setting the style in the first place...

Comment: The CSS worked great, until I tested in in IE, in IE it's not working.

Comment: When working with wordpress sites, I find myself using `!important` more and more... It's helpful, but there's something about it that just makes me cringe.

Comment: Actually I found why it's not working, I found a "customs" stylesheet and tossed it in there.  Great tip, thanks!  BTW, I hate wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can write a CSS rule for `#whats-new-post-in-box` `.audio_controls` and mark it with `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to hide the inner div, and this requires jQuery:

```
$('div.audio_controls', $('#whats-new-post-in-box')).hide();
```

This code select all div elements with an `audio_controls` class that are inside the element with an id of `whats-new-post-in-box`, and hides them.