# Overriding the CSS in the style tag

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have the following HTML and CSS which is generated by the jQuery Mobile Framework. I have NO control on the generated HTML. I can only style them.

```
<div class="ui-popup-container slideup in ui-popup-active" id="productSummaryOverlay-popup" tabindex="0" style="max-width: 1201px; top: 0px; left: 17px;">
```

I want to ignore or remove everything in the style attribute as it is making it impossible to go full screen and it is also giving a margin which I do not want.

How can I ignore the style attribute?

Comment: You tried use !important?

Comment: Maybe a little JavaScript? `.setAttribute("style", "");`

Comment: it was explained well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366227/trying-to-override-a-dynamically-generated-inline-style, hopefully this may help you out

  [1]:

Comment: Thanks everyone! I solved the problem by using the !important as suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use !important at the end of the line:

```
#productSummaryOverlay-popup {
    max-width: none !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use !important to set styles with greater priority
Like

```
.slideup{
  top: 50px !important;
}
```

Also you can controll styles with jQuery ( and js ) - like setAttribute('style', ... or .style property